# Jest Expect toContainEqual() not working with escape characters

Tags: javascript, jestjs

When using Jest to expect strings with escape characters, it doesn't work correctly.

The actual string I want to test: "abc\"

code:

`expect("abc\\").toContainEqual("abc\\");`

result:

[image]

Comment: [_"Use `.toContainEqual` when you want to check that an item with a specific structure and values is contained in an array."_](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tocontainequalitem)

Answer (score 1):

Use toContain() instead of toContainEqual() when asserting for substrings.